# Autocommit with PDO

Tags: php, pdo, transactions, rollback, autocommit

The rollback of my transaction doesn't work.
How do I set autocommit to false (or 0) in the php script using PDO (I have InnoDB 5.7.18) ?

Here is my code:

```
     global $bdd;  //defined with PDO

       try {                             
            $bdd->beginTransaction();
            /* my requests */
            $bdd->commit();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $bdd->rollBack();
            return $e->getMessage();
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: PDO::beginTransaction () method disables auto-commit mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my problem myself: a few of my tables were in MyISAM (whereas the majority are in InnoDB -> I work with an old database system...); so the rollback didn't work for these tables. Once I changed them into InnoDB, it worked.
Thanks to everybody for the help !

Answer (score 3):

```
 $db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=employee');
 $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT,0);
 var_dump($db->query('SELECT @@autocommit')->fetchAll());
```

Comment: thanks for the answer; the var_dump gave me that: "array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["@@autocommit"]=> string(1) "0" [0]=> string(1) "0" } }", but the autocommit is still to "ON" when I enter in mysql "SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name='autocommit';"  .... and the rollback still not work... :(

Comment: Make sure, Database definition language (DDL) statement such as DROP TABLE or CREATE TABLE, in MySQL, cannot be used within transactions.

Comment: Have You tried - $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, 0 ); $dbh->beginTransaction();

Comment: yes I have tried this, and I only use UPDATE requests in my transaction... :(

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the following attribute:

```
$bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT,0);
```

Comment: Were you set this attribute? try to set it when you opening a connection with database

Comment: It doesn't work either... but thank you for your help !