# PDO return success but no data is updated on database

Tags: php, pdo

when i try to update a row with `PDO` function it returned **success** and when i check database there was no data updated

so i followed this question [PDOStatement::execute() returns true but the data is not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646319/pdostatementexecute-returns-true-but-the-data-is-not-updated) which has answers already but didn't work here is what i did

[image]

**Below is code i tried**

```
<?php
$Fuid = '105199239598939142575';
sendOT($Fuid);
echo '<br>Below is var_dump() Rsult<br>';
check($Fuid);

function sendOT($Fuid) {
    try {
        $phone = '6381211774';
        $otp = '1234';
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DBHOST . ";port=3306;dbname=" . DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
        $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("UPDATE members SET verification_code=:veri_code AND phone=:phone WHERE Fuid=:Fuid");
        $stmt2->bindParam(':Fuid', $Fuid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt2->bindParam(':veri_code', $otp, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt2->bindParam(':phone', $phone, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt2->execute();
        echo 'Updated succeeded';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e;
    }
}

function check($Fuid) {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DBHOST . ";port=3306;dbname=" . DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
    $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE Fuid=:Fuid");
    $stmt2->bindParam(':Fuid', $Fuid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt2->execute();
    $unr = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    var_dump($unr);
}
?>
```

**Output**

[image]

as per the answer in this question [PDOStatement::execute() returns true but the data is not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646319/pdostatementexecute-returns-true-but-the-data-is-not-updated) may be there is no row with `WHERE` so i tried with the same `WHERE` with `SELECT` query and it showed result.

WHY is my UPDATE query doesn't update in database?

Comment: Do you have `autocommit` disabled?

Comment: @Barmar `autocommit` where should i check for ?

Comment: `SELECT @@autocommit;`

Comment: @Barmar so like this ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45235685/3836908

Comment: Just type it into an interactive query like phpMyAdmin, MySQL Workbench, or the `mysql` command line utility.

Comment: @Barmar this is what it return `array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["@@autocommit"]=> int(0) [0]=> int(0) } }1`

Comment: what is the data type?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Will it work when you use the same connection and not restart a new one per query? Why not check for errors after executing the query?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After many tries i managed to update with this query.

```
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("UPDATE members SET verification_code=:veri_code, phone=:phone WHERE Fuid=:Fuid");
```

it worked after removing `AND` from query using como `,` in update queries.